# Can anyone provide me how to give validation in React Typescript?

Tags: react-typescript

I need validation in length of characters in fields also email and mobile. If empty field is there it should show some message.

I am new to this technology and I don't have much knowledge. It's better if there is no form tag used.

Answer (score 0):

```
here is a sample code.
```

```js
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { InferType } from 'yup';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import _ from '@lodash';
import FuseSvgIcon from '@fuse/core/FuseSvgIcon';
import AvatarGroup from '@mui/material/AvatarGroup';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { UserType } from 'app/store/user';
import jwtService from '../../auth/services/jwtService';

/**
 * Form Validation Schema
 */
const schema = yup.object().shape({
    email: yup.string().email('You must enter a valid email').required('You must enter a email'),
    password: yup
        .string()
        .required('Please enter your password.')
        .min(4, 'Password is too short - must be at least 4 chars.'),
    remember: yup.boolean()
});

const defaultValues = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    remember: true
};

/**
 * The sign in page.
 */
function SignInPage() {
    const { control, formState, handleSubmit, setError, setValue } = useForm({
        mode: 'onChange',
        defaultValues,
        resolver: yupResolver(schema)
    });

    const { isValid, dirtyFields, errors } = formState;

    useEffect(() => {
        setValue('email', 'admin@fusetheme.com', { shouldDirty: true, shouldValidate: true });
        setValue('password', 'admin', { shouldDirty: true, shouldValidate: true });
    }, [setValue]);

    function onSubmit({ email, password }: InferType<typeof schema>) {
        jwtService
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((user: UserType) => {
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                console.info(user);

                // No need to do anything, user data will be set at app/auth/AuthContext
            })
            .catch((_errors: { type: 'email' | 'password' | `root.${string}` | 'root'; message: string }[]) => {
                _errors.forEach((error) => {
                    setError(error.type, {
                        type: 'manual',
                        message: error.message
                    });
                });
            });
    }

    return (
        <div className="flex min-w-0 flex-1 flex-col items-center sm:flex-row sm:justify-center md:items-start md:justify-start">
            <Paper className="h-full w-full px-16 py-8 ltr:border-r-1 rtl:border-l-1 sm:h-auto sm:w-auto sm:rounded-2xl sm:p-48 sm:shadow md:flex md:h-full md:w-1/2 md:items-center md:justify-end md:rounded-none md:p-64 md:shadow-none">
                <div className="mx-auto w-full max-w-320 sm:mx-0 sm:w-320">
                    <img
                        className="w-48"
                        src="assets/images/logo/logo.svg"
                        alt="logo"
                    />

                    <Typography className="mt-32 text-4xl font-extrabold leading-tight tracking-tight">
                        Sign in
                    </Typography>
                    <div className="mt-2 flex items-baseline font-medium">
                        <Typography>Don't have an account?</Typography>
                        <Link
                            className="ml-4"
                            to="/sign-up"
                        >
                            Sign up
                        </Link>
                    </div>

                    <form
                        name="loginForm"
                        noValidate
                        className="mt-32 flex w-full flex-col justify-center"
                        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                    >
                        <Controller
                            name="email"
                            control={control}
                            render={({ field }) => (
                                <TextField
                                    {...field}
                                    className="mb-24"
                                    label="Email"
                                    autoFocus
                                    type="email"
                                    error={!!errors.email}
                                    helperText={errors?.email?.message}
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    required
                                    fullWidth
                                />
                            )}
                        />

                        <Controller
                            name="password"
                            control={control}
                            render={({ field }) => (
                                <TextField
                                    {...field}
                                    className="mb-24"
                                    label="Password"
                                    type="password"
                                    error={!!errors.password}
                                    helperText={errors?.password?.message}
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    required
                                    fullWidth
                                />
                            )}
                        />

                        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center sm:flex-row sm:justify-between">
                            <Controller
                                name="remember"
                                control={control}
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <FormControl>
                                        <FormControlLabel
                                            label="Remember me"
                                            control={
                                                <Checkbox
                                                    size="small"
                                                    {...field}
                                                />
                                            }
                                        />
                                    </FormControl>
                                )}
                            />

                            <Link
                                className="text-md font-medium"
                                to="/pages/auth/forgot-password"
                            >
                                Forgot password?
                            </Link>
                        </div>

                        <Button
                            variant="contained"
                            color="secondary"
                            className=" mt-16 w-full"
                            aria-label="Sign in"
                            disabled={_.isEmpty(dirtyFields) || !isValid}
                            type="submit"
                            size="large"
                        >
                            Sign in
                        </Button>

                        <div className="mt-32 flex items-center">
                            <div className="mt-px flex-auto border-t" />
                            <Typography
                                className="mx-8"
                                color="text.secondary"
                            >
                                Or continue with
                            </Typography>
                            <div className="mt-px flex-auto border-t" />
                        </div>

                        <div className="mt-32 flex items-center space-x-16">
                            <Button
                                variant="outlined"
                                className="flex-auto"
                            >
                                <FuseSvgIcon
                                    size={20}
                                    color="action"
                                >
                                    feather:facebook
                                </FuseSvgIcon>
                            </Button>
                            <Button
                                variant="outlined"
                                className="flex-auto"
                            >
                                <FuseSvgIcon
                                    size={20}
                                    color="action"
                                >
                                    feather:twitter
                                </FuseSvgIcon>
                            </Button>
                            <Button
                                variant="outlined"
                                className="flex-auto"
                            >
                                <FuseSvgIcon
                                    size={20}
                                    color="action"
                                >
                                    feather:github
                                </FuseSvgIcon>
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </Paper>

            <Box
                className="relative hidden h-full flex-auto items-center justify-center overflow-hidden p-64 md:flex lg:px-112"
                sx={{ backgroundColor: 'primary.main' }}
            >
                <svg
                    className="pointer-events-none absolute inset-0"
                    viewBox="0 0 960 540"
                    width="100%"
                    height="100%"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax slice"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                    <Box
                        component="g"
                        sx={{ color: 'primary.light' }}
                        className="opacity-20"
                        fill="none"
                        stroke="currentColor"
                        strokeWidth="100"
                    >
                        <circle
                            r="234"
                            cx="196"
                            cy="23"
                        />
                        <circle
                            r="234"
                            cx="790"
                            cy="491"
                        />
                    </Box>
                </svg>
                <Box
                    component="svg"
                    className="absolute -right-64 -top-64 opacity-20"
                    sx={{ color: 'primary.light' }}
                    viewBox="0 0 220 192"
                    width="220px"
                    height="192px"
                    fill="none"
                >
                    <defs>
                        <pattern
                            id="837c3e70-6c3a-44e6-8854-cc48c737b659"
                            x="0"
                            y="0"
                            width="20"
                            height="20"
                            patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                        >
                            <rect
                                x="0"
                                y="0"
                                width="4"
                                height="4"
                                fill="currentColor"
                            />
                        </pattern>
                    </defs>
                    <rect
                        width="220"
                        height="192"
                        fill="url(#837c3e70-6c3a-44e6-8854-cc48c737b659)"
                    />
                </Box>

                <div className="relative z-10 w-full max-w-2xl">
                    <div className="text-7xl font-bold leading-none text-gray-100">
                        <div>Welcome to</div>
                        <div>our community</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="mt-24 text-lg leading-6 tracking-tight text-gray-400">
                        Fuse helps developers to build organized and well coded dashboards full of beautiful and rich
                        modules. Join us and start building your application today.
                    </div>
                    <div className="mt-32 flex items-center">
                        <AvatarGroup
                            sx={{
                                '& .MuiAvatar-root': {
                                    borderColor: 'primary.main'
                                }
                            }}
                        >
                            <Avatar src="assets/images/avatars/female-18.jpg" />
                            <Avatar src="assets/images/avatars/female-11.jpg" />
                            <Avatar src="assets/images/avatars/male-09.jpg" />
                            <Avatar src="assets/images/avatars/male-16.jpg" />
                        </AvatarGroup>

                        <div className="ml-16 font-medium tracking-tight text-gray-400">
                            More than 17k people joined us, it's your turn
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Box>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SignInPage;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**